# gl_get_version returns different values depending on the SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES

Tags: python, opengl, sdl

gl_get_version returns two different values depending on these lines of code

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1)
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, 2)
```

With these lines returns 1.1 and without - 2.1 or greater.
Why is this happening? It's kind of a mistake or do so should be? Changing only these two lines and everything. Used PYTHON and CYTHON, OS - Windows.

I am trying to fix https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3576. 
These attributes are set here https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/window/_window_sdl2.pyx#L96

Comment: Please post how you call `gl_get_version`.

Comment: Sounds like your GL implementation does not support multisampling, and it falls back to microsoft's sw renderer (which doesn't support it either).

Comment: 2.1 _or_ greater? As in you get different version numbers besides **1.1** and **2.1**? It sounds like you have several different implementations. Check more than just the version number, also check the vendor and renderer names.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman 2.1 on my pc, greater - on any others pc`s

Comment: Oh, okay. Then you are hitting the GDI implementation of OpenGL because your driver does not support a certain feature. It's actually best to avoid doing MSAA this way whenever possible. In GL3+, the preferred method is to use an FBO with multisampled attachments and then blit to the screen. The benefit to doing that is that you can change MSAA settings on-the-fly without destroying your context.

Comment: @Martin During that meet the following files  https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/core/gl/__init__.py#L40  https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/graphics/opengl_utils.pyx#L236

Comment: Maybe I found the source of the problem. For support SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS requires the GL_ARB_multisample extension(according this http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GLattr) , and i don`t have it.